# use aggregate functions [ perform calculation ] on unicode column sql server

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I have one unicode column nvarchar in sql server database.
I am storing numeric values in that column in my localized "Indian Language GUJARATI".
How can i use aggregate functions like sum,avg on that nvarchar column.

Note : That nvarchar column contains unicode data in localized language.

Comment: If you want to do math on a column then it shouldn't be an NVARCHAR

Comment: If it's a number, **store it as a number!**

Comment: Do you possibly mean that your numbers are *not* represented with Arabic numerals (`0123456789`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got following procedure in both sql server and .net.

Convert English to Gujarati Unicode and
Convert Gujarati Unicode to English numbers

### .net Code

```
public static class global
{
    public static string Translate(string source, string fromStr, string toStr)
    {

        string result = "";
        foreach (var sourceChar in source)
        {
            int pos = fromStr.IndexOf(sourceChar);
            if ((pos >= 0) && (pos < toStr.Length))
            {
                result += toStr[pos];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string ToGujDig(this object   source)
    {
        string fromStr = ".0123456789";
        string toStr = ".\u0AE6\u0AE7\u0AE8\u0AE9\u0AEA\u0AEB\u0AEC\u0AED\u0AEE\u0AEF\u0AF0";

        string result = "";
        string s = source.ToString();

        foreach (var sourceChar in s)
        {
            int pos = fromStr.IndexOf(sourceChar);
            if ((pos >= 0) && (pos < toStr.Length))
            {
                result += toStr[pos];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string ToEngDig(this string  source)
    {
        string fromStr =     ".\u0AE6\u0AE7\u0AE8\u0AE9\u0AEA\u0AEB\u0AEC\u0AED\u0AEE\u0AEF\u0AF0";
        string toStr = ".0123456789";

        string result = "";
        string s = source.ToString();

        foreach (var sourceChar in s)
        {
            int pos = fromStr.IndexOf(sourceChar);
            if ((pos >= 0) && (pos < toStr.Length))
            {
                result += toStr[pos];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

### sql server code

1. pass numeric value and get unicode value

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NumericToUnicode]
   (
         @String VARCHAR(50)
   )
   RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)

   BEGIN

   DECLARE @rString NVARCHAR(50) 
   set @rString= N''

   DECLARE @length INT 
   set @length = LEN(@String)

   DECLARE @position INT 
   set @position= 1

   WHILE @position <= @length
   BEGIN

         IF (ASCII(SUBSTRING(@String, @position, 1))) = 46
               SET @rString = @rString + N'.'
         ELSE
               SET @rString = @rString + NCHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@String, @position, 1)) + 2742)
               SET @position = @position + 1
   END

   RETURN @rString

   END

   -- Test it
   SELECT [dbo].[NumericToUnicode]('50.0')  or
   SELECT [dbo].[NumericToUnicode](50.12)
   ```
2. Pass unicode value and get Numeric value

   ```
   Create  FUNCTION [dbo].[UnicodeToNumeric]
   (
       @nString NVARCHAR(50)
   )
   RETURNS NUMERIC(12,2)
   BEGIN 

   DECLARE @rString NVARCHAR(50) 
   set @rString=''

   DECLARE @position INT 
   set @position=1

   WHILE @position <= LEN(@nString)
   BEGIN
       IF (UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@nString, @position, 1))) = 46
           SET @rString = @rString + CHAR(UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@nString, @position, 1)))
       ELSE
                   SET @rString = @rString + CHAR(UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@nString, @position, 1)) - 2742)
       SET @position = @position + 1

   END

   RETURN @rString
   END
   ```

Hope this helps.